# Terminology for Using a Cognate for Prestige/to Mimic

Tags: cognates

Is there specific terminology to describe when a cognate word is used because of its relation to another language?

As an example: a modern English author writing about the Vikings choosing to use *yield* instead of *money* or *payment* because *yield* is cognate to *gjald* where as *payment* is from French.

Comment: I would call it stylisation (stylization), as in "speech stylization" or "dialect stylization" - e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/4169120?seq=1 or https://www.jstor.org/stable/40207944?seq=1

Comment: that seems like it's pointing me down the correct path

Comment: _Register_ is a term that gets used in this regard. One speaks of some lexical items being in a 'higher register'. The limiting case, of course, is [Javanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javanese_language#Registers), where almost every word has three or more variants that one can mix and match for various effects.

Comment: I had considered _register_ but was under the impression that register pertained more to a spectrum of formality. Perhaps accommodation? But that doesn't describe it well either.